# Why does OnLinkPrefixLength differ to adapter PrefixLength?

Tags: windows, winsock, ipv6

If you take the MSDN example inside [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows 7 SP1 then expand out enumeration of unicast addresses:

```
char s[1024];
for (i = 0; pUnicast != NULL; i++) {
  inet_ntop (pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family,
      pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET ?
      (PVOID)&((struct sockaddr_in*)pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr)->sin_addr :
      (PVOID)&((struct sockaddr_in6*)pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr)->sin6_addr,
      s, sizeof (s));
  printf ("\t#%lu %s/%u\n",
      i, s, (unsigned)pUnicast->OnLinkPrefixLength);
  pUnicast = pUnicast->Next;
}
```

and prefix details:

```
char s[1024];
for (i = 0; pPrefix != NULL; i++) {
  inet_ntop (pPrefix->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family,
      pPrefix->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET ?
      (PVOID)&((struct sockaddr_in*)pPrefix->Address.lpSockaddr)->sin_addr :
      (PVOID)&((struct sockaddr_in6*)pPrefix->Address.lpSockaddr)->sin6_addr,
      s, sizeof (s));
  printf ("\t#%lu %s/%u\n",
      i, s, pPrefix->PrefixLength);
  pPrefix = pPrefix->Next;
}
```

But one adapter shows the following output:

```
Length of the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESS struct: 376
IfIndex (IPv4 interface): 15
Adapter name: {84C25EC1-7ABB-4D6E-B8C7-8DEE08961EE2}
#0 2001:0:4137:9e76:2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/64
#1 fe80::2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/64
Number of Unicast Addresses: 2
...
#0 ::/0
#1 2001::/32
#2 2001:0:4137:9e76:2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/128
#3 fe80::/64
#4 fe80::2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/128
#5 ff00::/8
Number of IP Adapter Prefix entries: 6
```

The prefix list is correct, albeit slightly expanded over MSDN's description of 3 addresses:

> On Windows Vista and later, the linked
>   IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX structures pointed
>   to by the FirstPrefix member include
>   three IP adapter prefixes for each IP
>   address assigned to the adapter. These
>   include the host IP address prefix,
>   the subnet IP address prefix, and the
>   subnet broadcast IP address prefix. In
>   addition, for each adapter there is a
>   multicast address prefix and a
>   broadcast address prefix.

I determine the list is correct by comparing with the output of `netstat -r`:

```
IPv6 Route Table
==================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 15     58 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 15     58 2001::/32                On-link
 15    306 2001:0:4137:9e76:2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/128
                                    On-link
 14    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 15    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 15    306 fe80::2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/128
                                    On-link
 14    281 fe80::6153:a573:f691:8167/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 15    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
==================================================
```

However my interpretation of the API is that `OnLinkPrefixLength` should return 32 for the global-scope unicast address but the Vista+ only API is returning 64, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A bit of background information:**
There are a few default prefix lengths for IPv6. A LAN usually has a prefix length of 64. The link local addresses you see (fe80::/64) are examples of that. The addresses of your own system show up as single addresses in the routing table (/128). The multicast addresses are special (ff00::/8) as they don't correspond to one address of one host but to a group of multiple hosts on potentially multiple networks.

The /32 you are seeing is the Teredo address block (2001:0000::/32 == 2001::/32). Teredo is a IPv6-in-IPv4 tunneling protocol that Windows automatically configures. The routing table shows that your default IPv6 route (::/0) is through the Teredo adapter. Your system doesn't seem to have 'normal' IPv6 global unicast.

**Summary:**
The on-link-prefix-length is usually /64. Teredo is a special case and uses a fixed 'special' /32. Your own IPv6 addresses are complete and have a prefix length of /128.

You are right in that 2001:0:4137:9e76:2443:d6:ba87:1a2a/64 doesn't make sense. It is Teredo so it should have a network prefix length of /32. If it is a single IPv6 address it should have a prefix length of /128. The /64 does not make sense for Teredo and seems to be a bug.